# How to show content that is not yet translated (Untranslated Content)

Tags: views, i18n-l10n

I am fairly new to Drupal – spent the last 3 months getting to know my way around. I have one question. I have to create a multi-language site for English and German users. I'm the site administrator and all the content editors are German. They will upload content in German. From both our sides we will upload content in either German or English and then it should be translated into the other language.

I am looking for a way to show content that has not yet been translated – so that we know those items still need a translation.

I have all the language and translation core modules installed for Drupal 9.

I thought I could do this with a view using filtering for Content: Default translation (= True) Content: Revision translation affected (!= False), but that doesn't seem to work. It will show me pages that I know have already been translated.

Is there any way to accomplish this task? – even with a module.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/translation_views